# Response.Redirect Not Working in Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I am using An UdatePanel In the client side and using response.redirect in code behind.But it doesn't work because of updatepanel.Is there any way to implement response.redirect while using updatepanel.I googled,saw many answers,but doesn't get exact answer.

```
  <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="loading">
            <div class="loader">
                <center>
        Please wait...<br />
        <img src="images/loadinfo.gif" alt="Loading..." />
      </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

code behind

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            statuslabel.Text = "Updated Successfully,Redirecting....";
            Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "2;URL=Printsticker.aspx?itemId=" + hdApplication.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Response.Redirect`:

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Printsticker.aspx?itemId=" + hdApplication.Value);
}
```

According to my tests, it works for a button inside an UpdatePanel. I am using ASP.NET 4.0, which could make a difference, according the [this article](https://www.onceinawhitemoon.net/2011/10/responseredirect-inside-an-updatepanel/). The author mentions that he had problems with `Response.Redirect` and UpdatePanels in older versions of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Since Update Panel is updated via AJAX calls you cannot really do server-side redirect.

But you can change location via client-side script:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scr", string.Format("location.href='Printsticker.aspx?itemId={0}';", hdApplication.Value), true);
```

Comment: Are there special conditions where `Response.Redirect` does not work? When I try it, I don't see any problem (from the event handler of a button inside an UpdatePanel).

Comment: @ConnorsFan if you button triggers partial postback of UpdatePannel - normal page lifecycle isn't happening, page is updated via AJAX calls, hence Response.Redirect won't work (though the code will compile and not throw any errors)